# How do I create a valid installation package?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, deployment

I'm using the latest Visual Studio 2010, with C# 3.5 and my project is working fine on my machine.

I'm using SQLite for the database, and it's just a little .db file.

What's the best way for me to package this simple little application?

What is the preferred way to create a project that's setup for deployment?

Comment: Forgot to mention: Runs on Windows Desktop with Windows Forms. It also uses SQLite and references I think a SQLite dll file so that would have to be packaged as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your app is to be run on a desktop - if that's not the case you'll have to clarify.

You need to add a setup & deployment project to your solution and configure it to install the build output from your application as well as whatever content you want (ie: your .db file) onto the end user's machine.

The process is fairly straightforward and there are TONS of tutorials online -- Google is your friend for nitty gritty details.

Comment: Thanks for the name of the project I need. All of the guides you mention I find are from 2005,2006. Do you recommend a newer tutorial somewhere online?

Comment: setup & deployment projects haven't changed much in the last few years, so I think that even the ones from a few years ago will meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use NSIS (from Nullsoft). Free and really a pleasure to work with. It comes with samples and tutorials and you will find a lot of info on Google.

You can deploy your app in a few minutes if you don't want too much installer customization.